# How to paginate using Python Selenium in Trip Advisor to extract reviews

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the reviews with their respective titles of a particular hotel in Trip Advisor, using Web Scraping techniques with Python and Selenium but I have only been able to extract the reviews of a single page and I need to extract **all or most of the reviews**, but the **pagination** is **not working**. What I do is click on the Next button, iterate over a range of pages and extract the information.

The web scraping is from the home page https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g562644-d1490165-Reviews-Parador_de_Alcala_de_Henares-Alcala_De_Henares.html
notice that when the page changes this is added: -or20- depending if it is the fourth -or30- or fifth -or40- always shows 10 reviews

for example this is the third page: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g562644-d1490165-Reviews-or20-Parador_de_Alcala_de_Henares-Alcala_De_Henares.html

Basically this is what I do:  read a csv, open the page, (change to all laguanges, this is optional), expand reviews, read reviews, click on Next button, write to csv, iterate in a range of pages.

Any help, thanks in advance !!

Images:
[Trip Advisor HTML reviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCiDj.png)

[Trip Advisor HTML Next button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O2G8.png)

This is my code so far:

```
# Web scraping
# Writing to csv
with open('reviews_hotel_9.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write('titles, reviews \n')
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g562644-d1490165-Reviews-Parador_de_Alcala_de_Henares-Alcala_De_Henares.html")
sleep(3)
cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')# cookies accept

try:
    cookie.click()
except:
    pass
print('ok')

for k in range(10): #range pagination
    #container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-reviewid]")
    try:
        # radio button all languages (optional)
        #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="component_14"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/ul/li[1]/label/span[1]'))))
        # read more expand reviews
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="Ignyf _S Z"]')))) 
        # review titles
        titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="KgQgP MC _S b S6 H5 _a"]/a/span') #
        sleep(1)
        # reviews
        reviews = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//q[@class="QewHA H4 _a"]/span')#
        sleep(1)
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
    with open('reviews_hotel_9.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        for i in range(len(titles)):
            file.write(titles[i].text + ";" + reviews[i].text + "\n")

    try:
        #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="ui_button nav next primary "]')))) # 
        # click on Next button
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ui_button nav next primary ')))) 
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
    file.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: could you explain clearly, what exactly u need from the page

Comment: I need to extract all the reviews and its titles from a hotel.

Comment: SO lets say from this page `https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g562644-d1490165-Reviews-Parador_de_Alcala_de_Henares-Alcala_De_Henares.html#REVIEWS` ypu want to extract review from all the pages right?

Comment: Where is titles?

Comment: Yes, I need to extract all the reviews and titles reviews from this page: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g562644-d1490165-Reviews-Parador_de_Alcala_de_Henares-Alcala_De_Henares.html,  each review has a title, they are in the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scrape data from each review page by clicking on the `Next` button on the review page. In the code below we go on an infinite loop and keep clicking the `Next` button. We stop going ahead when we encounter the exception `ElementClickInterceptedException`. At the end we are saving the data to the file `MyData.csv`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
import pandas as pd
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
s = Service(chrome_path)
url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g562644-d1490165-Reviews-Parador_de_Alcala_de_Henares-Alcala_De_Henares.html'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(url)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['title', 'review'])
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    reviews = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.WAllg._T')
    for review in reviews:
        title = review.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.KgQgP.MC._S.b.S6.H5._a').text
        review = review.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.fIrGe._T').text
        df.loc[len(df)] = [title, review]
    try:
        driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.ui_button.nav.next.primary').click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        break

df.to_csv("MyData.csv")
```

This gives us the output :

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot sir, I executed your code it doesn't work at all though, only scraped one page I think this exception `ElementClickInterceptedException` cuts the loop so it just scrapes one page,

Comment: also i would add this too `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="Ignyf _S Z"]'))))` in order to show the whole review because they are truncated

Comment: @Ventor for the given url there were 29 review pages, did you mean only first one was scraped? And not the other 28? Weird cuz it executes on my setup

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! it worked fine Mr. Himanshu you are great !!. this is solved